# Convert Uint8Array to Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have Uint8Array instance that contains binary data of some file.
I want to send data to the server, where it will be deserialized as byte[].
But if I send Uint8Array, I have deserialization error.

So, I want to convert it to Array, as Array is deserialized well.
I do it as follows:

```
    function uint8ArrayToArray(uint8Array) {
        var array = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < uint8Array.byteLength; i++) {
            array[i] = uint8Array[i];
        }

        return array;
    }
```

This function works fine, but it is not very efficient for big files.

**Question: Is there more efficient way to convert Uint8Array --> Array?**

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can use the following in environments that support [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) already (ES6)

```js
var array = Array.from(uint8Array)
```

When that is not supported you can use

```js
var array = [].slice.call(uint8Array)
```

Comment: Yes , [].slice works fine, and it is more compact. But it seems not more efficient. Takes ~5 sec for 10mb file. (

Comment: .entries() (and/or .values()) returns ArrayIterator object, not array.

Comment: Nitpicking here, but you're just a tiny bit better off calling Array.prototype.slice.call instead of [].slice as it saves an unnecessary array construction.

Comment: I just wanna say that even 6 years later this is perfect. My 6 million line file takes just seconds.

Answer (score -1):

There is a method of Uint8Array using the prototype (but it only supported by Firefox and Chrome):

TypedArray.prototype.entries() --> it returns a array.

Check it out:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/entries

Comment: No, it is ArrayIterator object. Read in link.

Comment: Ooo, I see, my mistake ! sorry to don't be helpful for you! Good luck!