# How to properly use fromCharCode.apply with Uint8Array in TypeScript 3?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, uint8array

So I have some code that I inherited that looks like this: 

`String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(license));`

Recently, we had to update the project dependencies and we are not on TypeScript 3 which complains that the code is not correct with this message:

`Argument of type 'Uint8Array' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
  Type 'Uint8Array' is missing the following properties from type 'number[]': pop, push, concat, shift, and 3 more.`

I have a few other places with the same errors, and they are all Uint8Array except one that is a Uint16Array. The issue seems to be with some changes to the Uint8Array constructor that has several overloads. I have tried changing the code to 

`const jsonKey: string = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Array.from(new Uint8Array(license)));`

and 

`const jsonKey: string = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(new Uint8Array(license)));`

Neither of these has worked to recreate the original function of the code, but they did suppress the error messages.

Comment: Can you share a sample 'license' value? 

This might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29676964/4375436.

Comment: I will get a sample license shortly, however the solution you linked is the equivalent of the one I tried with `Array.prototype.slice.call` that didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do something which will be easier to read even if not as compact:

```
let jsonKey: string = "";
(new Uint8Array(license)).forEach(function (byte: number) {
    jsonKey += String.fromCharCode(byte);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt almost worked; you just need to explicitly specify the generic parameter:

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Array.from<number>(new Uint8Array(license)));
```