# Argument of type 'Uint8Array' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'

Tags: javascript, typescript

Based on [crypto.subtle.exportKey("spki", cryptoKey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/exportKey) I want to convert the returned `ArrayBuffer` into a string so I can turn it into a base64 string. Based on the documentation I tried

```
const bufferAsString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buffer));
```

but TypeScript tells me

> TS2345: Argument of type 'Uint8Array' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.

How can I fix the type errors?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603770/how-to-properly-use-fromcharcode-apply-with-uint8array-in-typescript-3

Comment: Side note: <https://github.com/tc39/proposal-arraybuffer-base64/>, if adopted, will likely make this solution obsolete. Though of course, it’d need to be polyfilled on older environments…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use parameters spread when you call the function instead of using apply ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gUwJ4wLwwO4EswBMQYB0wATkgA5QiEQCuARlADYICwAUDDIQOYJgISAQygIA0sgAUHLlwDeM2VzBCAtggBcMAEQAlAMoBBALQAFffu0AaRUoD0dmAGFwELLkExabsDxhCYABYABgBOADZjeixYRBQAMxASGAgkaARVCBgoAAsRGBIEAEdaLEKYJnAeY1ESVRSEYFoSGKRbWVUQXFombwAZfh5crQAmYMCADhtOJRhyBiYsYABRAA9ycH4oLQEMGABVHCgJwxJhJEkAbQBGKxhgu%20uAXQBKadmYPIgcrW19AAkTCMAKzhaztAC%2071kUBItAQ0K4l20bh4YGsOgAboIsPEkNonooXhwOPFaGBgFAsOB-PQRtASJJ6LR4lpTucAEIs%20KCF4wBQzQpQZpgGD6WE4HiEeIkECqJx5EguDySQhq3YHI4nM5CC7M%20IvF4Abg4EJJ7DsACoOGsNiRYLkEDAeFhsaK4v48JgWqIYDE-WAqNkck7tAh1klRLhjHFtClyEJgAhCBxLXYOEJUhSYGSKVSaeG7VAnGRKCAJBc4loSxQqBW%20QKuKBILBC5GELg0P4MEJ-dg8ARiKWqDQGMxk237RXJNpyHBgBAJhi4sbFM3oDBJ1HDBBxS1fF2hHSGZItx3VzN162I-aOzuOZmEOFAl3%20-giIwQEJTzft7uJb4F5Nq4sDkBktrtp26AAAbGHBcEcssADiACSAByMCmLoKEAGqGAAKssMBiMsACa8FwQAOmAAAkchnrg96Ps%20ELURRxjLGhAAimHYXhhHEWR7HQSa7BriBm6-hWADytBQPMsDoPgTTqIGhAlIISD6AgLCUkkM6EAxMbINoQF%20vEP5FjJckKQA-IQoirMW4CiIGfJbtZ8lyQ54bOYGWxdmBqgQbeuCiRCQA)):

```
String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(buf));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use spread syntax or `Array.from` to convert the `Uint8Array` to a regular array.

```js
String.fromCharCode.apply(null, [...new Uint8Array(buffer)]);
```

Comment: Why the `[...new Uint8Array(buffer)]` if it's already fed into `apply`? It doesn't need specifically, an array, any array-like would do. And a typed array is an array-like.

Comment: Also, if it's going to be spread anyway, might as well do `String.fromCharCode(...typedArray)`

Comment: @VLAZ I agree that `String.fromCharCode(...typedArray)` is better here. TypeScript complains about just passing `new Uint8Array(buffer)` to apply though.